# Filter nested list by map key

Tags: django, list, filter

I have a list like given in bellow. I want to filter this data using "map" key.

```
    [
        { 
          "model": "map.mapreferencepoints", 
          "pk": 3,
          "fields": {"map": 2, "referenceName": "RF1", "corX": 906, "corY": 377}},
        {
          "model": "map.mapreferencepoints",
          "pk": 4,
          "fields": {"map": 1, "referenceName": "RF2", "corX": 1017, "corY": 377}},
        {
          "model": "map.mapreferencepoints",
          "pk": 5,
          "fields": {"map": 2, "referenceName": "RF3", "corX": 1171, "corY": 377}}
    ]
```

I want to get data has only map = 1 like;

```
  [
     {  
        "model": "map.mapreferencepoints",
        "pk": 4,
        "fields": {"map": 1, "referenceName": "RF2", "corX": 1017, "corY": 377}
     }
  ]
```

How can I filter data by map key in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = [
        { 
          "model": "map.mapreferencepoints", 
          "pk": 3,
          "fields": {"map": 2, "referenceName": "RF1", "corX": 906, "corY": 377}},
        {
          "model": "map.mapreferencepoints",
          "pk": 4,
          "fields": {"map": 1, "referenceName": "RF2", "corX": 1017, "corY": 377}},
        {
          "model": "map.mapreferencepoints",
          "pk": 5,
          "fields": {"map": 2, "referenceName": "RF3", "corX": 1171, "corY": 377}}
    ]

filtered_list = [i for i in my_list if i["fields"]["map"] == 1]
```